# How to compute SMA for months based on weeks data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have a `dataframe` with `100 Keys(column 1)` and `6 months` data (from Jan to June in column format like `2019_Jan_Week1,2019_Jan_Week2 etc. till June)`. Agenda is to `forecast for future 3 months (from July to Sep)` using Simple Moving Average of last 6 months. For instance, for July Week1 forecast the moving `average` should be calculated using `2019_Jan_Week1,2019,Feb_Week1,2019_Mar_Week1,2019_Apr_Week1,2019_May_Week1, and 2019_Jun_Week1`. 
The question is how to effective and speedily compute this operation?
Currently I am using For loop which takes huge amount of time?

I have tried using for loop, but it is taking huge amount of time.

```
counter=1
for keyIndex in range(0,len(finalForecastingData)):
    print(keyIndex)
    for forcastingMonthsIndex in range(31,columns):
        finalForecastingData.iloc[keyIndex,forcastingMonthsIndex] = finalForecastingData.iloc[keyIndex,counter]+finalForecastingData.iloc[keyIndex,counter+5]+finalForecastingData.iloc[keyIndex,counter+10]+finalForecastingData.iloc[keyIndex,counter+15]+finalForecastingData.iloc[keyIndex,counter+20]
        counter = counter+1
    counter=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You can very easily get a rolling mean with pandas `.rolling('60d').mean()`. For that you need to convert the time data into pandas `Datetime` format with `pd.to_datetime()` and set it as index with `set_index()`.

You should also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It really helps to give example data. With a sample DataFrame it becomes much easier to give you concrete code rather than a direction where to look.

Comment: But rolling will not consider intermediate values for addition, right? I mean to calculate SMA for July Week1 which is at 31st column.....we have to add Jan Week1 with Feb, Mar,Apr,May and June Week1 which is at the locations 1,5,10,15,20,25.....they are not continuous to use rolling....

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to split the date into month and weeknumber and  `groupby('weeknumber')` should do the job. However, please create an example DataFrame and your desired output.

Comment: Product to Forecast:- ABC Shampoo. Forecast should be done using SMA of last 2 months. Forecast is to be done for month MARCH WEEK 1. Given is the data of 2 months, JAN and FEB, but data is in WEEK format like, 2019_Jan_Week1, 2019_Jan_Week2,2019_Jan_Week3, 2019_Jan_Week4m 2019_Feb_Week1, 2019_Feb_Week2, 2019_Feb_Week3, 2019_Feb_Week4 (consider these are columns in excel......) and target is to find SMA for 2019_Mar_Week1 which is mean of 2019_Jan_Week1 and 2019_Feb_Week1. I can't using ROLLING function since there are other weeks info also between 2019_Jan_Week1 and 2019_Feb_Week1.